# Displaying A Remote Image Over Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple 16x16 grid of thumbnail images and when one is clicked, I want to display the full sized one with the background dimmed and the image in a div appearing to float above the dimmed background.

I don't want to prepopulate a list of the full-sized

```
$('#photo-grid').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {     // Gets the URL of full-sized image
    $('.page-cover').css('opacity', 0.6).fadeIn(300);  // Makes background appear to fade
    $('#lightbox-img').attr('src', data.url);          // Sets image src in hidden DIV
    $('#lightbox-img').one('load', function() {
      var lbi;
      lbi = $('#lightbox-img');

      console.log("lbi: " + (lbi.width()) + " x " + (lbi.height()));  // always 0
      console.log("lbi: " + (lbi.width()) + " x " + (lbi.height()));  // always 0

      $('.image-display').css('width', parseInt(lbi.css('width')).toString() + "4px")
        .css('padding-left', '2px');
      $('.image-display').css('height', parseInt(lbi.css('height')).toString() + "4px")
        .css('padding-top', '2px');

      return $('.image-display').css('opacity', 1.0).fadeIn(300);
    });
    return $('#lightbox-img').each(function() {
      console.log("triggering for cached image " + this.complete);
      if (this.complete) {
        return $(this).load();
      }
    });
  });
  return false;
});
```

So here is where I'm failing to understand things. At the point where I do `lbi = $('#lightbox-img');` I know that the image has loaded either from the server or the local cache. However, neither the query `width()` and `height()` functions, nor the CSS ever show any width or height for the image. I've stepped through this in the Chrome and Safari debuggers and can't see that these attributes are actually set when the image is loaded.

I know there are tons of modal lightbox plugins but this is such a simple piece of code it seems like overkill to use one. I have exactly one image to display per click and I can do all the layout stuff in a few lines of code.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Happen to have a live fiddle or example I we can play with?

Comment: It seems like it isnt as simple as you thought. Why put yourself through this? Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some thing where I'm not quite sure why. For example, `.css('width', parseInt(lbi.css('width')).toString() + "4px")` basically multiplies the width by ten then adds 4.

However, when I throw your code in a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/X9GWp/ , I don't get the issue you report, so I can't say much about why it doesn't work for you. I've had to make some guesses about the css, html and data, so that might be why it's different. If you provide your own fiddle I could have a look.

---

Anyway, here is a very basic `lightbox` loosely based on your codesnippet, but without getting the image-url from a JSON request.

javascript:

```
/* when lightbox is clicked, fade out */
$('.page-cover').on('click', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(400);
    $('#lightbox-img').hide();
});

/* when image is loaded, fade in */
$('#lightbox-img').load(function(){
    $(this)
       .css('top', ($(window).height()-$(this).height())/2)
       .fadeIn(300);
});

/* when thumbnail is clicked, load href as image source and fadein lightbox-background*/
$('#photo-grid').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#lightbox-img').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    $('.page-cover').fadeIn(300); 
});
```

css:

```
.page-cover {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display:none;
}

#lightbox-img
{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="photo-grid">
    <a href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/nature/1" /></a>
</div>

<div class="page-cover"><img id="lightbox-img" /></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xLQpZ/

Comment: As it turns out, the inferences you drew were that I had written the HTML and CSS in parallel so you wrote it correctly. I accidentally reused the `.image-display` container selector so my script was affecting the wrong element. Great answer, and better than my initial implementation!